# Remove Taxonomy from Homepage in SPS2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, taxonomy

I want to remove Intranet Taxonomy icon appearing on my Homepage in Edit Mode in SharePoint 2013. Please check link for better understanding : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDpXM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Edit the page layout that page is using with SharePoint Designer and remove the Taxonomy field.

Comment: I thought that can easily be done with editing the master page (seattle,master) through SPD 2013. However, cant find while searching for Taxonomy in seattle.master (advanced mode)

Am I following a wrong path?

Comment: any update, pls help.

Comment: It is not in the .master page but in the Page Layout file that the page has been configured to use.